# Calling an implemented function of child instance from abstract parent class in C#

Tags: c#, instance, abstract-class, radix

Here it is:

```
abstract class IA
{
  public virtual void ChangePropertyOfAIChild()
  {
    b.value = true;
  }
}
...
class B:IA
{
   bool value;

}

class C:IA
{
   bool value;
}
....
///main
IA newBInstance = new B();
newBInstance.ChangePropertyOfAIChild();

IA newCInstance = new C();
newCInstance .ChangePropertyOfAIChild();

/////
```

What would be a proper way of calliing an already implememnted function in a child's class from the base abstract class and changing it's value? 
Thanks!

Comment: If B is a child of A, how would A know that (or even care that) B exists? Your hierarchy is backwards

Comment: Am I missing something here? This code doesn't even compile. How are you going to access a property of something that doesn't even exist?

Answer (score 1):

As @Camilo Terevinto pointed out, you heirarchy is wrong. try:

```
public abstract class IA
{
  public bool value;

  public virtual void ChangePropertyOfAIChild()
  {
    value = true;
  }
}

public class B : IA
{ }

public class C : IA
{ }

// in main
IA newBInstance = new B();
newBInstance.ChangePropertyOfAIChild();

IA newCInstance = new C();
newCInstance.ChangePropertyOfAIChild();
///
```

Your sample code had the base abstract class trying to change the value of a field in a class it doesn't know about:

> (b.value = true)

For the base class to be able to do this, the field needs to be declared inside the base class.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have't got your inheritance quite right.

If this is your class implementation:

```
public abstract class IA
{
}

public class B : IA
{
    public bool value;
}

public class C : IA
{
    public bool value;
}
```

And then if you create an instance of `IA` like so:

```
IA newBInstance = new B();
```

Then compiler goes ahead and creates an instance of `IA`. Since your `IA` does NOT have a property called `value`, you cannot access it.

You have two options, either use the method suggested by CodexNZ in the previous reply, or simply cast your `newInstance` to `B` and directly set `value`. Like this:

```
IA newBInstance = new B();
((B)newBInstance).value = true;
```

However this is counter intuitive since if you can do that you might as well create an instance of `B` in the first place. So I recommend the previous method. This is more to explain *why* your logic doesn't work.

Please refer to a tutorial [like this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_inheritance.htm) to learn more. There are tons of more resources on the internet.